# How to add custom web form to Joomla site

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, joomla

Can anyone please tell me if this is possible? I'd like to add a form to my joomla site with javascript validation, the data doesn't need to be stored in a database, it needs to be posted to a web service.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: it's possible. read tutorials and documentation, or find an existing extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Dmitry's answer above for a ready made component or module where you can get this

Alternatively you can write a component yourself using JFormField http://docs.joomla.org/Form_field and The component tutorial here: http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component . Joomla Form Fields have built in validation as you can see in the example component tutorial for the backend (however this works just the same in the front end).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms) is the variety of such extensions. Hope, you will find one that suits your needs.